# WinBUGS returns "variable na is not defined". How to fix it?

Tags: r, winbugs

I am using WinBUGS to deal with a network meta-analysis. The code and data is listed below. The problem is, when I run the code, WinBUGS always returns "variable na is not defined", and doesn't work.

na[] means the number of arms within one trial. I don't know how to define it within the code. Actually in some code examples other authors didn't define them too. Can anyone possibly help me out? Much appreciated!

NMA
rate of SAE.
10 treatments for T2DM

```
model{                   # *** PROGRAM STARTS

  for(i in 1:ns){          # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
    w[i,1] <- 0  # adjustment for multi-arm trials is zero for control arm
    delta[i,1] <- 0      # treatment effect is zero for control arm
    mu[i]  ~  dnorm(0,.0001)       # vague priors for all trial baselines
    for (k in 1:na[i]) {     # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
      r[i,k]  ~  dbin(p[i,k],n[i,k]) # binomial likelihood
      logit(p[i,k]) <- mu[i] + delta[i,k] # model for linear predictor
      rhat[i,k] <- p[i,k] * n[i,k] # expected value of the numerators

      #Deviance contribution
      dev[i,k] <- 2 * (r[i,k] * (log(r[i,k])-log(rhat[i,k]))
                       + (n[i,k]-r[i,k]) * (log(n[i,k]-r[i,k]) - log(n[i,k]-rhat[i,k]))) }

    # summed residual deviance contribution for this trial
    resdev[i] <- sum(dev[i,1:na[i]])
    for (k in 2:na[i]) {     # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
      # trial-specific LOR distributions
      delta[i,k]  ~  dnorm(md[i,k],taud[i,k])
      # mean of LOR distributions (with multi-arm trial correction)
      md[i,k] <- d[t[i,k]] - d[t[i,1]] + sw[i,k]
      # precision of LOR distributions (with multi-arm trial correction)
      taud[i,k] <- tau *2*(k-1)/k
      # adjustment for multi-arm RCTs
      w[i,k] <- (delta[i,k] - d[t[i,k]] + d[t[i,1]])
      # cumulative adjustment for multi-arm trials
      sw[i,k] <- sum(w[i,1:k-1])/(k-1)
    }
  }
  totresdev <- sum(resdev[])     # Total Residual Deviance
  d[1]<-0    # treatment effect is zero for reference treatment
  # vague priors for treatment effects
  for (k in 2:nt){ d[k]  ~  dnorm(0,.0001) }
  sd  ~  dunif(0,5) # vague prior for between-trial SD
  tau <- pow(sd,-2) # between-trial precision = (1/between-trial variance)

  # pairwise ORs and LORs for all possible pair-wise comparisons, if nt>2
  for (c in 1:(nt-1)) {
    for (k in (c+1):nt) {
      or[c,k] <- exp(d[k] - d[c])
      lor[c,k] <- (d[k]-d[c])
    }
  }
  # ranking on relative scale
  for (k in 1:nt) {
    rk[k] <- nt+1-rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “good”
    # rk[k] <- rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “bad”
    best[k] <- equals(rk[k],1) #calculate probability that treat k is best
  }
}
# *** PROGRAM ENDS      

DATA
   #Description of data inputs
   #ns = Number of studies
   #nt = Number of treatments (including placebo)
   #t[,x] = Treatment indicator
   #r[,x] = Number achieving response on HAM-D (50% improvement of scores from baseline)
   #n[,x]= Number of all randomized patients (ITT)
   #na[] = Number of arms in study
list(ns=19, nt=12)

t[,1]   r[,1]   n[,1]   t[,2]   r[,2]   n[,2]   t[,3]   r[,3]   n[,3]   na[]
3   0   76  30  2   72  NA  NA  NA  2
3   99  1389    23  132 1383    NA  NA  NA  2
1   6   352 30  2   178 NA  NA  NA  2
2   6   106 30  3   95  NA  NA  NA  2
3   49  393 25  18  198 NA  NA  NA  2
1   20  65  22  10  26  NA  NA  NA  2
1   1   76  30  3   76  NA  NA  NA  2
3   7   441 26  1   220 NA  NA  NA  2
2   1   47  30  0   41  NA  NA  NA  2
3   10  156 30  9   150 NA  NA  NA  2
1   4   85  25  5   85  30  4   84  3
3   6   152 30  5   160 NA  NA  NA  2
18  4   158 21  8   158 NA  NA  NA  2
1   3   110 30  2   111 NA  NA  NA  2
3   3   83  30  1   92  NA  NA  NA  2
1   3   124 22  6   123 30  4   125 3
3   236 1553    23  254 1546    NA  NA  NA  2
6   5   398 7   6   403 NA  NA  NA  2
1   64  588 22  73  584 NA  NA  NA  2
END
```

I really need to fix it within this week. Thanks!

Comment: It does not look like you are using `R`.  It looks like maybe you are working directly in `WinBUGS`.  Did you write the model code or did you obtain the model code in its current state?

Comment: Yes Mark. I am using it directly in WinBUGS with its current state. Do you have any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I always call OpenBUGS or JAGS through R.  I virtually never use WinBUGS directly.  If the complete code for R was included I might be able to help.

Comment: WinBUGS and OpenBUGS are almost same thing. The code are exactly the same. But I didn't try it through R. I just tried by WinBUGS and OpenBUGS, and got the problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, I rewrote my codes in R, but still meet some new problems. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009206/how-to-fix-undefined-columns-selected-for-network-meta-analysis-in-r

Comment: could you give me some hints for R debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem solved or not.
You should load dada 2 times.
first time, load the "list"
second time, load the "t[,1]   r[,1]   n[,1]   t[,2]   r[,2]   n[,2]   t[,3]   r[,3]   n[,3]   na[]"
then , it works.
Hope it benefit for you!

Comment: thanks! The problem was solved, but your answer gives a better solution.