# how to fix "undefined columns selected" for network meta-analysis in R?

Tags: r, networking

I am conducting a network meta-analysis on R with two packages, gemtc and rjags. However, when I type

```
Model <- mtc.model (network, linearmodel=’fixed’).
```

R always returns “

> Error in [.data.frame(data, sel1 | sel2, columns, drop = FALSE) :
>   undefined columns selected In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   mtc.model(network, linearModel = "fixed") :   Likelihood can not be
>   inferred. Defaulting to normal. 2: In mtc.model(network, linearModel =
>   "fixed") :   Link can not be inferred. Defaulting to identity “

How to fix this problem? Thanks!

I am attaching my codes and data here:

```
SAE <- read.csv(file.choose(),head=T, sep=",")
head(SAE)
network <- mtc.network(data.ab=SAE)
summary(network)
plot(network)

model.fe <- mtc.model (network, linearModel="fixed")

plot(model.fe)
summary(model.fe)
cat(model.fe$code)
model.fe$data

# run this model
result.fe <- mtc.run(model.fe, n.adapt=0, n.iter=50)
plot(result.fe)
gelman.diag(result.fe)

result.fe <- mtc.run(model.fe, n.adapt=1000, n.iter=5000)
plot(result.fe)
gelman.diag(result.fe)
```

following is my data: SAE

```
    study treatment responder sample.size
1      1         3         0          76
2      1        30         2          72
3      2         3        99        1389
4      2        23       132        1383
5      3         1         6         352
6      3        30         2         178
7      4         2         6         106
8      4        30         3          95
9      5         3        49         393
10     5        25        18         198
11     6         1        20          65
12     6        22        10          26
13     7         1         1          76
14     7        30         3          76
15     8         3         7         441
16     8        26         1         220
17     9         2         1          47
18     9        30         0          41
19    10         3        10         156
20    10        30         9         150
21    11         1         4          85
22    11        25         5          85
23    11        30         4          84
24    12         3         6         152
25    12        30         5         160
26    13        18         4         158
27    13        21         8         158
28    14         1         3         110
29    14        30         2         111
30    15         3         3          83
31    15        30         1          92
32    16         1         3         124
33    16        22         6         123
34    16        30         4         125
35    17         3       236        1553
36    17        23       254        1546
37    18         6         5         398
38    18         7         6         403
39    19         1        64         588
40    19        22        73         584
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reading the manual `?mtc.model`. It clearly states the following:

> Required columns [responders, sampleSize]

So your `responder` variable should be `responders` and your `sample.size` variable should be `sampleSize`.

Next, your `plot(network)` should help you determine that some comparisons can not be made. In your data, there are 2 subgroups of trials that were compared. Treatment 18 and 21 were not compared with any of the others. Therefore you can only do a meta-analysis of 21 and 18 or a network meta-analysis of the rest.

```
network <- mtc.network(data.ab=SAE[!SAE$treatment %in% c(21, 18), ])
model.fe <- mtc.model(network, linearModel="fixed")
```